# Haskell: convert String to Field for mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, haskell, custom-data-type

What is the best way to convert a string `"[\"id\"=:5977, \"brandId\"=:87]"` to a field for mongoDB `["id"=:5977, "brandId"=:87]`

or even better if I have a datatype

```
data Body = Body
 { body_id :: int
   brandId :: Int } deriving (Show)
```

giving

`Body {body_id = 5977, brandId = 87}`

What is the best way to convert that to

`["id"=:5977, "brandId"=:87]`

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you mean "for mongodb"? Do you want to convert to json? If yes there's the aeson package. More information can help.

Comment: @sinelaw the field syntax for Database.MongoDB is  as I posted above. I don't know ; their example is  `access pipe master "dbname" $ insert "collection" ["author" =: "Mike"]` . So I am trying to figure out how to convert on datatype to fit that field format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you are using [hackage: mongoDB](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mongoDB) to interact with a database.

So the only thing to do is convert a haskell value to a BSON-value this is what [hackage: bson](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bson) provides, notably in the typeclass [Val](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bson-0.3.2.1/docs/Data-Bson.html#t:Val)

> ```
> class (Typeable a, Show a, Eq a) => Val a where
>
> Haskell types of this class correspond to BSON value types
>
> Minimal complete definition
> val, cast'
>
> Methods
> val :: a -> Value 
> ...
> cast' :: Value -> Maybe a 
> ...
> ```

so it remains to implement `val` and `cast'`

but first of all we need to derive a few more properties than you have:

`Body.hs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveDataTypeable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
module Body where

import Data.Bson
import Data.Typeable

data Body = Body { bodyID :: Int
                 , brandID :: Int }
                 deriving (Show,Typeable,Eq)


instance Val Body where
  val (Body body brand) = Doc [ "bodyID"  := (Int64 $ fromIntegral body)
                              , "brandID" := (Int64 $ fromIntegral brand)]

  cast' (Doc bson) = case (bson !? "bodyID") of
                          Just (Int64 x) ->
                               case (bson !? "brandID") of
                                         Just (Int64 y) -> Just (Body (fromIntegral x)
                                                                      (fromIntegral y))
                                         Just _  -> Nothing
                                         Nothing -> Nothing
                          Just _ -> Nothing
                          Nothing -> Nothing
  cast' (Array x) = undefined
  cast' _ = Nothing
```

this is a bit clustered but rather straightforward.

---

Now I gave this thing a bit more thought - the previous `cast'` is really clustered and haskell having nice abstractions should do better

```
  val (Body body brand) = Doc [ "bodyID"  := (val body)
                              , "brandID" := (val brand)]
  cast' (Doc bson) = do body  <- (bson !? "bodyID")
                        brand <- (bson !? "brandID")
                        Body <$> cast' body <*> cast' brand

  cast' _ = Nothing
```

So you really could write this a bit shorter accepting that `<$>` (called `fmap`) and `<*>` (called `ap` do the "right" thing.

Moreover I used `do` notation to simplify the job, now using this

```
> cast' $ val (Body 30 4) :: Maybe Body
Just (Body {bodyID = 30, brandID = 4})
```

*Note* in the last example you really need the annotation `:: Maybe Body` otherwise the compiler cannot figure out what to cast and you'll get a `Nothing`.

Comment: the `fromIntegral` are necessary as Value only knows `Int32` and `Int64` so you need to convert them

Comment: the second version of `cast'` is one of the many reasons why i really like haskell - short, elegant and pretty understandable even if you don't know the language, even though producing it as a newcomer is not trivial

Comment: thank you. I am learning Haskell and finding it really hard at the moment; but people like you are a great help. That works beautifully.

Comment: could you explain why `Doc [ "bodyID"  := (Int64 $ fromIntegral body),                   "brandID" := (Int64 $ fromIntegral brand)] ` becomes ` Doc [ "bodyID"  := (val body) , "brandID" := (val brand)]` ? Thanks!